How to Fix Issues in R Code for Metropolis-Hastings Algorithm Applied to Gumbel Type II Distribution?
I am trying to implement the Metropolis-Hastings (M-H) algorithm in R to sample from the posterior distribution of a Gumbel Type II distribution. However, I'm encountering issues with my implementation, and I'm not getting the expected results. Below is my code and a detailed explanation of my approach. In this case, I used the proposed distribution as normal and gamma for the parameters location (-inf < ϕ < +inf ) and scale (φ > 0) and the conjugate prior Normal for ϕ and Gamma for φ.
library(ismev)
library(extraDistr)

# Supply the number of iterations
N <- 10000

# Dimension of parameters
alfa <- length(N + 1)
beta <- length(N + 1)

## Data
n <- 10
X <- c(0.91, 4.07, 1.66, 4.23, -0.48, 5.38, 0.61, -0.36, 7.26, 2.36)

## Fit Gumbel distribution
gum.fit(x)
## $mle 1.851347 3.129131

# ni is the scale parameter of Normal distribution for ϕ and gamma for φ
ni1 <- 10000
ni2 <- 1.5

# Step 1. Initializing the algorithm
parameter_1[1] <- 0
parameter_2[1] <- 3.12

# Step 3. Evaluating the posterior function (ϕ = a; φ = b)
jointpost <- function(a, b) {
  loglikelihood <- -n * log(b) - (n / b) * (mean(x) - a) - sum(exp((-x - a) / b))
  prior <- 1 / a
  jointpost <- prior * exp(loglikelihood)
  return(jointpost)
}

# cont is counter of rejection number in generation of SIGMA
cont1 <- rep(0, times = N)
cont2 <- rep(0, times = N)

# Step 4: Applying the M-H algorithm
for (i in 1:N) {
  # Propose new value for ϕ
  prop1 <- rnorm(1, mean = parameter_1[i], sd = ni1)
  aux1 <- jointpost(prop1, parameter_2[i]) / jointpost(parameter_1[i], parameter_2[i])
  num1 <- dnorm(parameter_1[i], mean = prop1, sd = ni1)
  den1 <- dnorm(prop1, mean = parameter_1[i], sd = ni1)
  h1 <- num1 / den1
  ratio1 <- h1 * aux1
  parameter1 <- min(1, ratio1)
  u1 <- runif(1)
  if (u1 < parameter1) {
    parameter_1[i + 1] <- prop1
  } else {
    parameter_1[i + 1] <- parameter_1[i]
    cont1[i] <- 1
  }
  
  # Propose new value for φ
  prop2 <- rnorm(1, mean = parameter_2[i] / ni2, sd = ni2)
  aux2 <- jointpost(parameter_1[i + 1], prop2) / jointpost(parameter_1[i + 1], parameter_2[i])
  num2 <- dgamma(parameter_2[i], shape = prop2 / ni2, scale = ni2)
  den2 <- dgamma(prop2, shape = parameter_2[i] / ni2, scale = ni2)
  h2 <- num2 / den2
  ratio2 <- h2 * aux2
  parameter2 <- min(1, ratio2)
  u2 <- runif(1)
  if (u2 < parameter2) {
    parameter_2[i + 1] <- prop2
  } else {
    parameter_2[i + 1] <- parameter_2[i]
    cont2[i] <- 1
  }
  cat(i, " ", "", " ", "100", "\n")
  flush.console()
}

But my code doesn't work or converge. Could anyone help?

Carlos, it's difficult for others to see subtle problems in someone else's code. The way to debug programs like yours is to first simplify the problem to where you can see exactly what's going on (by printing intermediate results), so that you can either verify it is correct for that simple case, or you see there is a bug which you can fix. Once you get the simple case working, then make it a little more complicated and repeat the process. This is an approach which works for any kind of numerical calculation.

... and is there a reason why you are re-inventing the wheel?  There are packages that implement MCMC algorithms that have had far more development and user time than any one individual could devote to the problem...
